# Greedy algorithm for Set Cover problem - need help with approximation

Tags: algorithms, approximation, set-cover

I want to approximate how close is the greedy algorithm to the optimal solution for the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which I'm sure most of you are familiar with, but just in case, you can visit the link above.
The problem is NP-Hard, and I'm trying to find a bound on how well does the greedy algorithm perform.
I know it looks a lot, but please bare with me. I pretty much did most of the work, I'm just missing that last small piece.

Here is the pseudo code:

Input: $U$ - set of elements, $F$ - family of sets s.t. $\bigcup_{S\in F}S=U$
Output: $C$ - a family of sets; $C\subseteq F$ s.t. $\bigcup_{S\in C}S=U$

```
initially C is empty

while U is not empty do:
    choose S from F that maximizes the cover of elements in U
    add S to C
    subtract S's elements from U

return C
```

The algorithm is pretty straight forward, and it is easy to see that it is indeed polynomial.

This is my attempt to approximate:
**Claim 1**: In a set $U$ of $m$ objects, that can be covered with $k$ sets, there has to be a set $S\subseteq U$ whose size is at least $\frac{1}{k}m$.
**Proof**: Trivial. (I decided not to prove it)

A corollary is that given the situation described in that claim, the greedy algorithm will choose a set whose size is at least $\frac{1}{k}m$.

**Claim 2**: Given a universe $U$, if there exist a cover of size $k$, then after $k$ iterations, the greedy algorithm will cover at least half of the elements, meaning at least $\frac{1}{2}n$ elements.
**Proof**: By claim 1, in the first iteration the algorithm will cover at least $\frac{1}{k}n$ elements. Upon entering the second iteration, there are at most $n-n\frac{1}{k}$ elements, and so the greedy algorithm will at least cover additional $\frac{1}{k}(n-n\frac{1}{k})$ elements. In general, on the $i$'th iteration, the algorithm will cover $\frac{1}{k}(n-n\frac{i-1}{k})$ elements. So after $k$ iterations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{k}(n-n\frac{i-1}{k})=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{k}(n-n\frac{i}{k})$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{n}{k}-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{ni}{k^2}=n-\frac{n}{k^2}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i$$
$$=n-\frac{n}{k^2}(\frac{k(k-1)}{2})=n-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{k-1}{k})\geq\frac{1}{2}n$$

OK, now this is where I need help: I know that in the first $k$ iterations, the algorithm picks at least half of the elements. After another $k$ iterations, another half was covered, out of what's left (meaning another $\frac{1}{4}n$). So in general, I know that the bound is $k\log n$, I just can't figure out how to formalize it.
What formula represents this behaviour? $T(ki)=T(\frac{1}{2^i}n)$ and solve for $i$? It didn't work...
What formula or equation should I solve to actually show that the number of iterations is bounded by $k\log n$?

Comment: You can simplify your analysis.  At each iteration, at least $1/k$ of the remaining elements are covered.  That is, at most $1-1/k$ of the remaining elements remain uncovered.  So, after $i$ iterations, by induction on $i$, at most $n(1-1/k)^i$ elements are not covered.  Using $1-1/k < e^{-1/k}$, this is less than $n e^{-i/k}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown that if there is a set cover of size $k$ and there are $n$ elements left uncovered, then the greedy algorithm finds $k$ sets which cover at least $n/2$ elements, and so at most $n/2$ elements are left uncovered. You can prove by induction that if there is a set cover of size $k$ and there are $n$ elements left uncovered, then for each $t$, the first $tk$ sets found by the greedy algorithm cover all but at most $n/2^t$ elements. The idea now is to pick a value of $t$ such that $n/2^t < 1$. Since the number of elements left uncovered by the algorithm is an integer, if the number $m$ of elements left uncovered satisfies $m < 1$, then in fact $m = 0$, i.e., all elements are covered.

As a side note, you can actually improve on your reasoning and show that the first $k$ sets cover at least $(1-1/e)n$ elements, and so leave only $n/e$ elements uncovered. This improves the bound from your $k\log_2 n$ to the sharp $k\ln n$, which is known to be tight (unless P=NP).

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. 
And yes, I know that there's a tighter bound of $k\ln n$, and even tighter than that ($H(\max\{|S|\mid S\in F\})$ where $H(n)$ is the harmonic number of order $n$). In fact, proving it is my next task... :)